# SQL Instance names not recognised in connection strings when WCF service deployed as Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services, connection-string

I have a WCF service built in C# and it uses a connection string to conncect to a Database.

connectionString="Data Source=AXSLV501\SQLA;Passwordxxx;User ID=xxx;Initial Catalog=E1DSPXDCDB"

This works perfectly when the WCF service is hosted as such within Visual Studio 2010, the connection works fine.

However, when I host the WCF service inside a Windows Service however I get a problem.  The service is hosted OK, however the database becomes unaccessable.

I can alter the conncetion string changing the instance name (\SQLA) for the port number (1433) like bellow and it works fine. 
"Data Source=AXSLV501,1433;Passwordxxx;User ID=xxx;Initial Catalog=E1DSPXDCDB"

I am curious as to why the instance name does not work when the service is hosted through a windows service, but does when hosted through visual studio.

Further to my curiosity I have a system which generates the connection strings automatically so without changing it I need the WCF service to work with instance names.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and .net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this in only have a user permissions issue. That Windows Service, ¿which Windows User is using?

- Start - Run - services.msc
- Find your service - Right click -
  Properties - User Login

More: Do you have any restriction in your Windows' Firewall? Maybe VStudio has all the traffic allowed, but that windows service, hasn't.

Comment: Its running under NETWORK SERVICE, I had assumed its a user permissions issue but thought it strange that it works with port number but not instance name

Comment: Maybe you have to take a look on SQL Server configuration manager. Check client protocols. Maybe you have only activated TCP/IP. Check if Named Pipes it's activated